# PyDev doesn't work with Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I want to make my first steps in Python 3, so I have installed Eclipse 4.3.1 and install the latest version of the PyDev Plugin. I have created two configurations for Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 (both versions are installed on my machine). I can run and debug my test program using Python 2.7 but I can only run my program using Python 3.2. If I want to debug my program, I get an error message saying "Unexpected error setting up the debugger Socket closed". In the console I get

```
File "/home/he/PyDev/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.2.0.201312292215/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 914
    if text.startswith(u'REPLACE:'):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The test program is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Hello, World!")
```

How can I fix this? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.0 ~ 3.2 does not support explicit unicode literal (`u'....'`).

Unicode literal is supported in Python 2.x, Python 3.3+.
(See [PEP 414 -- Explicit Unicode Literal for Python 3.3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/))

---

To make it run in Python 3.2, replace following line:

```
if text.startswith(u'REPLACE:'):
```

with:

```
if text.startswith('REPLACE:'):
```

By replacing the code as above, in Python 2.7, the literal `'REPLACE:'` denotes byte string. If you want `'REPLACE:'` work as unicode string like in Python 3.x, you can use [`__future__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).

Add following line at the top of the source code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```